# Magento 2.2.5: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input in checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, json, console

I have an error in my checkout page of Magento 2.2.5 image loader loading continuously in checkout page.Show error in console of google chrome

[image: h]

Comment: here the second error the unexpected end of json input refers there is some error in json, which may be return by the request. One more thing can you see the netwok tab and see is there any request which has 5XX, errors?

Comment: No request show in network tab only error  in google console